# paypal sandbox account's profile link not showing options

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

[image]

I created sandbox accounts in paypal developer console it been over 48 hours still i can't access profile settings. How much time it will take any idea?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Summary is when creating Business account First name must be set to Ryan and last name can be set to APPROVED and you will not see the pop up as above

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday. I called tech support this morning. The advice they gave me: create another sandbox testing account and try again. I did, and it worked this time.
Please follow 
https://github.com/PayPal-Mobile/ios-here-sdk-dist/blob/master/docs/Sandbox%20Guide.pdf to create sandbox account, just in case for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help this fixed my problem. I really appreciate it.